# Hourly backups for AWS instances

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, backup, snapshot

I’m looking for the best practices for taking hourly backups of my instances using AWS environment. I’m using both Ubuntu and Amazon Linux instances as web server without any panels used.

Hourly  snapshot is economic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take hourly EBS snapshots or you can create a process to copy your data to S3 hourly. What is "economical" is entirely subjective and you would need to provide more information about your requirements before I could answer that completely.

EBS snapshots are incremental, so if you created a snapshot hourly each snapshot would only be backing up the changes that had been written to the volume in the last hour. So from the perspective of the storage space you would be paying for, that would be a fairly economical way to provide hourly backups of EC2 instances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Is it possible to configure Incremental hourly snap shot with ubuntu/amazon linux server ?

Comment: Yes just schedule this script to run every hour https://github.com/CaseyLabs/aws-ec2-ebs-automatic-snapshot-bash

Comment: I tried with the above script but its not working as incremental, Every time creating as new snap shots.
=====
/opt/aws/ebs-snapshot.sh
$ Volume ID is vol-9c1bdb2e
#: New snapshot is snap-23c5e467
#: Checking snap-23c5e467...
#: Not deleting snapshot snap-23c5e467. Description: ip-172-31-41-52-/dev/sda1-backup-2016-04-17 ...
#: Checking snap-a19c6be6...
#: Not deleting snapshot snap-a19c6be6. Description: ip-172-31-41-52-/dev/sda1-backup-2016-04-17 ...
#: Checking snap-ff7ac3b9...
#: Not deleting snapshot snap-ff7ac3b9. Description: ip-172-31-41-52-/dev/sda1-backup-2016-04-17 ...
=====

Comment: But, it automatically created as new every time and old snap shots remains. Is there any way to overwrite new one.

Comment: So you only ever want a single snapshot from the last hour? I think that script keeps several snapshots by default. You should be able to change the code to delete all old snapshots. That totally defeats the purpose of incremental snapshots though.